# python Requests login to website returns 403

Tags: python, django, pyramid, python-requests

I'm trying to use `requests` to login to a website but as you can guess I'm having a problem

here's the the code that I'm using

```
import requests

EMAIL = '***'
PASSWORD = '***'
URL = 'https://portal.bitcasa.com/login'

client = requests.session(config={'verbose': sys.stderr})
login_data = {'username': EMAIL, 'password': PASSWORD,}
r = client.post(URL, data=login_data, headers={"Referer": "foo"})
print r
```

and if I print out `r.text` I get

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head><script type="text/javascript">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ||[];NREUMQ.push(["mark","firstbyte",new Date().getTime()])</script>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
  <title>403 Forbidden</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
    body { font:small sans-serif; background:#eee; }
    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
    h1 { font-weight:normal; margin-bottom:.4em; }
    h1 span { font-size:60%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
    #info { background:#f6f6f6; }
    #info ul { margin: 0.5em 4em; }
    #info p, #summary p { padding-top:10px; }
    #summary { background: #ffc; }
    #explanation { background:#eee; border-bottom: 0px none; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="summary">
  <h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
  <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>

</div>

<div id="explanation">
  <p><small>More information is available with DEBUG=True.</small></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">if(!NREUMQ.f){NREUMQ.f=function(){NREUMQ.push(["load",new Date().getTime()]);var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript";e.src=(("http:"===document.location.protocol)?"http:":"https:")+"//"+"d1ros97qkrwjf5.cloudfront.net/42/eum/rum.js";document.body.appendChild(e);if(NREUMQ.a)NREUMQ.a();};NREUMQ.a=window.onload;window.onload=NREUMQ.f;};NREUMQ.push(["nrfj","beacon-1.newrelic.com","0e859e0620",778660,"ZAZRbUcHWBAHURFYX11MdUxbBUIKCVxKVVpSDVRWGwtfBwJeAEZRQQYdWkYUUFklQRdXZloGRHRcAlIPA0UEQ1UdE0FWVgNFEDlEDFRH",0,7,new Date().getTime(),"","","","",""])</script></body>
</html>
```

They're using a combination of django and pyramid.

I've been playing around with this for about two days now but, obviously, have gotten nowhere. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The login page uses a CSRF token to prevent cross-site scripting attacks. You'll need to retrieve that token first.

The login page sets a cookie with the same token, we need to load the login page and grab that token first, before we pass this on to the login POST:

```
client = requests.session()

# Retrieve the CSRF token first
client.get(URL)  # sets the cookie
csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']

login_data = dict(username=EMAIL, password=PASSWORD, csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrftoken)
r = client.post(URL, data=login_data, headers={"Referer": "foo"})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm still getting the same error.  The logic makes sense though.  Perhaps the csrf_token needs to be passed into a different parameter on the `POST`? Can't find any information on Requests and csrf_tokens though.

Comment: @Jeff: The parameter is certainly correct; the browser would post it under the exact same name. It could be that the server has other measures in place, like testing the user agent string. That'll require trial and error. You can always see what your browser's developer tools tell you about what is POSTed when you log in.

Comment: Most likely the reason it was not working is the CSRF token needs to be requested inside of your requests.Session() object.  Otherwise the CSRF token will not be valid.

Answer (score 4):

as the error message suggests, you are missing the [csrf token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/)

you need to `GET` the login page first, read the csrf token and `POST` that back along with the rest of your form data

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It sounds like your approach is the same as Martijn's approach.  However I'm getting the same error trying to do this.  By best guess so far is that I'm not passing in the csrf_token into the correct parameter.  Would you happen to know where to pass it into?