# Login to webpage from script using Requests and Django

Tags: python, django, python-requests, django-authentication

I have written a web application in Django. I need to post some data to a form from a python script. The post (r2) works correctly when login is disabled. I have the request working correctly for the login (r1), but it gives me a 404 error now for the form post (r2). The login doesn't appear to be carried over to the second request. The csrftoken and sessionid are hardcoded for testing because it wasn't recognizing them. Relevant code (url base removed):

```
url_login='../pecasRunLog/accounts/login/'
url_add_run='../pecasRunLog/model/'+region+'/add_run/'

client = requests.session()
client.get(url_login)
csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']
login_data = {'username':user,'password':password, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken, 'next': '/pecasRunLog/'}
r1=client.post(url_login,data=login_data)

payload={'model_region':region_id,'scendir':scendir, 'mapit_scenario': schema, 'run_name':schema+timestamp, 'run_computer_name':os.environ['COMPUTERNAME'], 'run_computer_ip':get_lan_ip(), 'declared_user':declared_user, 'logged_in_user':getpass.getuser(), 'sd_schema':schema, 'sd_database':database, 'sd_host':get_lan_ip(), 'sd_port':pgport,'mapit_schema':schema, 'mapit_database':database, 'mapit_host':get_lan_ip(), 'mapit_port':pgport,'start_date':start_date, 'start_time':start_time, 'end_date':end_date, 'end_time':end_time,'logged_manually':3, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken, 'sessionid':'jtvv50cs3iyo9bjthbr2diujfmrrlsnf'}
r2=requests.post(url_add_run,payload)
```

Comment: should r2 be made from `client` instead of `requests`?

Comment: It doesn't recognize 'csrftoken' when I change it to 'client.post'. Both commands work separately, but not together.

Comment: Well, you can't expect your cookies from the first request to be sent with the second request if you don't use your session.

Comment: I also tried setting them up with separate requests for session and it didn't want to work. Same issue as in the answer below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not working in part because `r2` needs to have the cookies returned by `r1`. This may not fix it, but it is unlikely to work without making *at least* this change. To do this, you could use the same session throughout the script, or pass the cookies to each request after the first one.

Here is what using a session throughout might look like:

```
url_login='../pecasRunLog/accounts/login/'
url_add_run='../pecasRunLog/model/'+region+'/add_run/'

client = requests.session()
client.get(url_login)
csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']
login_data = {'username':user,'password':password,
  'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken, 'next': '/pecasRunLog/'}
r1=client.post(url_login,data=login_data)

payload={'model_region':region_id,'scendir':scendir, 
  'mapit_scenario': schema, 'run_name':schema+timestamp, 
  'run_computer_name':os.environ['COMPUTERNAME'], 
  'run_computer_ip':get_lan_ip(), 'declared_user':declared_user,
  'logged_in_user':getpass.getuser(), 'sd_schema':schema, 
  'sd_database':database, 'sd_host':get_lan_ip(), 
  'sd_port':pgport,'mapit_schema':schema, 
  'mapit_database':database, 'mapit_host':get_lan_ip(), 
  'mapit_port':pgport,'start_date':start_date, 
  'start_time':start_time, 'end_date':end_date, 
  'end_time':end_time,'logged_manually':3, 
  'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken, 
  'sessionid':'jtvv50cs3iyo9bjthbr2diujfmrrlsnf'}
r2=client.post(url_add_run,payload)
```

Here is what passing cookies throughout the script might look like:

```
url_login='../pecasRunLog/accounts/login/'
url_add_run='../pecasRunLog/model/'+region+'/add_run/'

# get the csrftoken
r0 = requests.get(url_login)
csrftoken = r0.cookies['csrftoken']

# get cookies with logged in info
login_data = {'username':user,'password':password,
  'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken, 'next': '/pecasRunLog/'}
r1=requests.post(url_login,data=login_data,cookies=r0.cookies)

# use logged-in cookies
payload={'model_region':region_id,'scendir':scendir, 
  'mapit_scenario': schema, 'run_name':schema+timestamp, 
  'run_computer_name':os.environ['COMPUTERNAME'], 
  'run_computer_ip':get_lan_ip(), 'declared_user':declared_user,
  'logged_in_user':getpass.getuser(), 'sd_schema':schema, 
  'sd_database':database, 'sd_host':get_lan_ip(), 
  'sd_port':pgport,'mapit_schema':schema, 
  'mapit_database':database, 'mapit_host':get_lan_ip(), 
  'mapit_port':pgport,'start_date':start_date, 
  'start_time':start_time, 'end_date':end_date, 
  'end_time':end_time,'logged_manually':3, 
  'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken,
  'sessionid':'jtvv50cs3iyo9bjthbr2diujfmrrlsnf'}
r2=requests.post(url_add_run,payload,cookies=r1.cookies)
```

If neither of these works, try looking carefully at the cookies, and maybe you'll spot the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Your first solution worked! I think I also had a combination of other unfinished functions that were affecting my testing.

Comment: this is was I was looking for! You saved my evening. Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

I just face same problem.

Looks like django use diferent url for login post than the login home page.

This code work for me

```
import requests
URL1='http://localhost:8000/admin/'
URL='http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/'
UN='bino'
PWD='sendhimin'
client = requests.session()

# Retrieve the CSRF token first
client.get(URL1)  # sets the cookie
csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']

login_data = dict(username=UN, password=PWD, csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrftoken)
r = client.post(URL2, data=login_data, headers={"Referer": "foo"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
url_login='../pecasRunLog/accounts/login/'
url_add_run='../pecasRunLog/model/'+region+'/add_run/'

with requests.session() as client:
    client.get(url_login)
    csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']
    login_data = {'username':user,'password':password, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken, 'next': '/pecasRunLog/'}
    r1=client.post(url_login,data=login_data)

    payload={'model_region':region_id,'scendir':scendir, 'mapit_scenario': schema, 'run_name':schema+timestamp, 'run_computer_name':os.environ['COMPUTERNAME'], 'run_computer_ip':get_lan_ip(), 'declared_user':declared_user, 'logged_in_user':getpass.getuser(), 'sd_schema':schema, 'sd_database':database, 'sd_host':get_lan_ip(), 'sd_port':pgport,'mapit_schema':schema, 'mapit_database':database, 'mapit_host':get_lan_ip(), 'mapit_port':pgport,'start_date':start_date, 'start_time':start_time, 'end_date':end_date, 'end_time':end_time,'logged_manually':3, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken, 'sessionid':'jtvv50cs3iyo9bjthbr2diujfmrrlsnf'}
    r2=client.post(url_add_run,payload)
```

If this works, I think the problem is that you first post from the newly created session, and then you do a regular post, while you should continue to post from the session

Comment: I tried that out earlier and tested it again now. It says 'csrftoken' is not defined. I had the same problem with the sessionid.

Comment: I've written a somewhat similar script a while back that doesn't use cookies, as the requests.session() maintains your session within the script. Perhaps try to remove the cookies aspect from both this code, and the server-side code, and then add them back in later, once this component works? See this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567507/passing-csrftoken-with-python-requests?rq=1

Comment: I see you're posting the `sessionid`. Might the `sessionid` change every time that the post is run? Try removing it from `payload`.