# CSRF verification fails on requests.post()

Tags: python, django

Can't figure this one out. The CSRF verification works fine in all my Django template views. Here I'm trying to post from a python client using techniques I've found in other posts. The client.get(url) call does provide the token (the debugger shows, for example: client.cookies['csrftoken'] = 'POqMV69MUPzey0nyLmifBglFDfBGDuo9') but requests.post() fails with error 403, CSRF verification failed. What's going on?

My Django view (with some dummy stuff in the methods):

```
class CameraUpload(View):
    template_name = "account/templates/upload.html"

    def get(self, request):
        dummy = VideoForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': dummy})

    def post(self, request):
        dummy = VideoForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': dummy})
```

And the client that's trying to do the post:

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/camera_upload/'

client = requests.session()
client.get(url)
csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']

payload = {
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken,
    'tag': '69'
}

r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

EDIT:

Tried adding the referer as per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567507/passing-csrftoken-with-python-requests/13569789#13569789) so code now looks like:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=dict(Referer=url))
```

but same problem exists.

Comment: you have an extra foreword slash in your url aka `/` you should probably remove that

Comment: That slash needs to be there. Removing it results in the following error: "You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data..."

Comment: well then the next question would be why do you have `APPEND_SLASH` set? an additional slash usually can mess things up especially on the front end (javascript etc.).. but I guess since you have it as a setting its ok? might not be the best practice though. my guess as to what is wrong is everytime you make a request its setting a cookie / certificate so sending the one from a previous request is messing up the next request.. but I don't know with what is provided..

Comment: I think I missed your comment before posting my edit but that's exactly right. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using your session (`client`) for the post:

```
r = client.post(url, data=payload, headers=dict(Referer=url))
```

Comment: Thanks! This turned out to be exactly my issue