# Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.) After CSRF token login success

Tags: python, django

I use below code to first login to my website to get the valid CSRF token, then I would like to use that token to make API call, however, it failed. Please help me..

```
import requests

LOGIN_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/admin/login/'
client = requests.session()
# Retrieve the CSRF token first
client.get(LOGIN_URL)
csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']
print('token:'+ csrftoken)
login_data = dict(username='xxxx', password='xxxx', csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrftoken)
r1 = client.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_data, headers=dict(Referer=LOGIN_URL))
print(r1.status_code, r1.reason)

print('token:'+ csrftoken)
API_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/collection/api/job_submit/'
payload = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken, 'value1': 'val', 'value2': 'val'}

r2 = client.post(API_URL, data=payload, headers={'referer': API_URL, 'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken})
print(r2.status_code, r2.reason)
```

And this is what I get from the server:

```
[24/Oct/2018 21:28:59] "GET /admin/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1806
[24/Oct/2018 21:28:59] "POST /admin/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[24/Oct/2018 21:28:59] "GET /accounts/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 404 91
2018-10-24 21:28:59,914 [WARNING] django.security.csrf: Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /collection/api/job_submit/
[24/Oct/2018 21:28:59] "POST /collection/api/job_submit/ HTTP/1.1" 403 1019
```

So, how can I pass the token correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567507/passing-csrftoken-with-python-requests

Comment: My LOGIN_URL is successful, I failed the second one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explained at the very end of Django's ["Cross Site Request Forgery protection" documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#why-might-a-user-encounter-a-csrf-validation-failure-after-logging-in):

> ### Why might a user encounter a CSRF validation failure after logging in?
>
> For security reasons, CSRF tokens are rotated each time a user logs
>   in. Any page with a form generated before a login will have an old,
>   invalid CSRF token and need to be reloaded. This might happen if a
>   user uses the back button after a login or if they log in a different
>   browser tab.

This also goes for cookies. After you log in, django will send a new csrf cookie to the client. This will be stored in `client.cookies` and replaces the old one. The django server does not keep any record of the old token, so that's why you get the "CSRF token missing or incorrect." response.

You can access the new token from `client.cookies['csrftoken']` as before.

```
r1 = client.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_data, headers=dict(Referer=LOGIN_URL))
csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']
```

In fact, you can just use the client cookie directly. This would have avoided this bug in the first place. Requests keeps track of cookies for you when you use `requests.session()`.

```
r2 = client.post(
    API_URL, 
    data=payload, 
    headers={'X-CSRFToken': client.cookies['crsftoken']}
)
```

When you use the x-csrftoken http header, I don't think there's any reason to also include the token in the post payload (request body).

Comment: I got client as undefined when I tried this

Comment: @LarissaFord: The answer only includes the lines that should be changed. The rest of the code is in the question. `client = requests.session()` etc.