# Scrape with requests page with CSRF token

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape results from this [booking website](https://www.booking.alilaurogruson.it/booking/services/datas). In the `POST request` in addition to the trip codes and date, there is also `_csrf` parameter which I assume is a `CSRF token`.
I've tried to get the session cookie and extract the `CSRF token` following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567507/passing-csrftoken-with-python-requests) but the cookie I get back has no `CSRF token`

`<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie JSESSIONID=W33kBCH5zFsyVhTyQL9L4Ibyq-KLGTBSD4h_IUNA.aru-270545 for www.booking.alilaurogruson.it/booking>]>`

```
def get_session_cookie():
    url = 'https://www.booking.alilaurogruson.it/booking/welcome/home'
    s = requests.Session()
    s.get(url, verify=False)
    print(s.cookies)
    if 'csrftoken' in s.cookies:
        # Django 1.6 and up
        csrftoken = s.cookies['csrftoken']
    else:
        # older versions
        csrftoken = s.cookies['csrf']
    return csrftoken
```

How can I successfully scrape the search results?

Comment: If you had succes with this, it would be very nice to see the code you mdae in the end, because I am struggling with a similar issue, and don't get past csrf verification, despite having the csrf token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_csrf` is provided on that page as a form parameter you would have to parse out with something like [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/).

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="666363ca-ffff-ffff-ffff-41a61e158e0f" />
```