# Pyton requests: Extracting data from payload

Tags: python, python-requests, extract, csrf, payload

this is my first ever question on here.

Currently I am looking into the Python requests module. I am trying to automate a task for which i need to pass on a csrf token.
The csrf token can be found in the payload of a previous request.

How can I extract the value out of the Payload?

Example Payload:

value1: ABCD

value2: EFGH

csrf_token: **the token I am looking for**

value3: false

Sorry if this is a dumb or easy question but I am not able to solve it right now.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing csrftoken with python Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567507/passing-csrftoken-with-python-requests)

Comment: @RoseGod I dont think so. In the webpages content I can find 2 csrf tokens which do not have the same value and I think I need to choose the one from the payload.
Or can I just use one of the ones in the content?

Comment: What is that example payload _really?_ You're just showing some text. Is it in JSON format? Don't try to interpret for us; show us the real details. The less you change, the better. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples of where the data you might be looking for is located.

```
import requests


response = requests.get('http://some_url')
# raise an exception if the status  code != 200
response.raise_for_status()

# the contents of the response. (bytes)
contents = response.contents

# the contents of the response if the contents are 
# formatted as JSON. (dictionary)
contents = response.json()

# the headers of the response. (dictionary)
headers = response.headers

# You also have to consider if you are using the correct HTTP protocol
payload = {}
response = requests.put('http://some_url', json=payload)
response = requests.post('http://some_url', json=payload)

# the responses are going to function just like when using the "get" protocol
```

Comment: First of all, Thank you!
In the meantime I looked around and extracted the csrf token from the pages content but it does not work. It gives me the error b'{"error":"CSRF Token mismatch"}'
As I said above, I think the right csrf token is located in the requests Form Data (Payload). Is there a way to extract it from there?

Comment: I would need to see exactly what you are trying to grab. You are mentioning "form" data when before it was "payload" data. which may be a post and not a get. and maybe the data you are looking for in encapsulated in the response to the post.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake in my code which i found by now. Was able to find the token now in the html.
Thank you for answering me and trying to help :)